# Trying to create object in main method , but getting error. Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, compiler-errors

When I am trying to create "Employee" object in main method , program is giving error.

```
class Employee: 
    empCount = 0

    def __init__( self , name , salary ):
        self.name = name ;
        self.salary = salary ;
        Employee.empCount += 1 ;

    def displayCount( self ):
        print( "Total Employee: %d" % Employee.empCount ) ;

    def displayEmployee( self ):
        print( " Name:  ",self.name ) ;

def main():
    emp1 = Employee("Alfanzo Cruz" ,3233)
#   emp2 = Employee(" Frernando " , 32323 ) ;
#   emp3 = Employee("Snoop Dogg",23232) ;

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

`

[image]

I have gone through various links but could not understand the problem , class is always global why it is giving error ? . I am beginner in python , and struck for hours in this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason behind error is indentation , people who are new to this pay attention to indentation.

```
   class Employee: 
    empCount = 0

    def __init__( self , name , salary ):
        self.name = name ;
        self.salary = salary ;
        Employee.empCount += 1 ;

    def displayCount( self ):
        print( "Total Employee: %d" % Employee.empCount ) ;

    def displayEmployee( self ):
        print( " Name:  ",self.name ) ;

def main():
    emp1 = Employee("Alfanzo Cruz" ,3233)
    #   emp2 = Employee(" Frernando " , 32323 ) ;
    #   emp3 = Employee("Snoop Dogg",23232) ;

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do, when you type python that calls the interpreter and runs the code, after it ran it is not in the memory anymore.

If you have a separate script in which you want to use the class, 
you just type in the beginning: import Employee (without ".py").
(It needs to be in the same project folder, or you need to add it to your system paths variable so it could find it)
when creating an object:

```
emp1 = Employee.Employee("name",1234)
```

I am not sure you need the main part, it is usually used, but this script only creates a class, so if it runs, nothing really happens.

Same time I think your code is missing at the very beginning:

```
class Employee:
```

(I usually use PyCharm)

Edited:
For the class save into (Employee.py):

```
class Employee:
    empCount = 0
    def __init__( self , name , salary ):
        self.name = name ;
        self.salary = salary ;
        Employee.empCount += 1 ;

    def displayCount( self ):
        print( "Total Employee: %d" % Employee.empCount ) ;

    def displayEmployee( self ):
        print( " Name:  ",self.name ) ;
```

Open New script or in console (same folder / Project):

```
import Employee 
emp1 = Employee.Employee("Alfonz",1234)
emp1.displayCount()
emp1.displayEmployee()
```

Comment: I have added "class Employee"  missed it by mistake. I am just trying to grasp the oop in python , so I took this example. If you can show me some code it will be really helpful.

Comment: I edited in the answer as there is easier to format code

Comment: you can also call the functions with:
    Employee.Employee.displayCount(emp1)